# Best way to clear a value in a loop ?

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine

I've been wondering about a coding practice I've had for some time and I wanted to know if:

- it had some importance
- there was a better way to do so

Imagine you have an update loop and two various states, A and B. In state A, you need a specific variable V that you wish to clear when exiting state A (or entering state B). So, what I usually do is creating a function in B saying that :

```
if V not null: 
    V  = null
```

Which means that each time I go into the loop, I check for the V not null condition. Does this have a cost ? Is there a cleaner way to do so ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: And at the end of the day you want V = null in every case. So why do you care to test it?

Comment: Reminds me of some codegolf thread, there are loads and loads of answers to this simple question, you can drive yourself crazy thinking about the most efficient way to do something.  Your example looks OK, and is "good enough" unless you're running on very limited hardware (very very)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually do it:

```
byte someValueType = 1;
object someRefType = null;


while (condition)
{
    // do stuff

    someValueType = 0; // assuming 0 is the default value
    someRefType = null;
}
```

The cost of doing this is (as far as I know) minimal. Both (the reference and the value) are on the stack, so don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you would switch states always simply assign the variable V to null, no need to check if its already null. The cost here would be minimal either way.

```
if(A) 
{
   V = null;
   goToA();
}
if (B) {
   V = null;
   goToB();
}
```